# Processing Model .model from Ubuntu to windows and "vice versa" Python Error

Tags: ubuntu, windows, qgis-processing, compatibility

I have prepared a processing model in Qgis 2.10 under ubuntu 15.04, I tried to test it on a Windows(7) pc with Qgis 2.10 and I got a Python error message, 
Then I tried the opposite way, I prepared the model on the Windows pc and transferred it to my ubuntu pc. Got the same error. 
someone knows how to solve it?
i post the screenshot of the error[image: Python model error]

Comment: no one can confirm this bug? c mon guys!